# Is there a difference between "Joe said" and "said Joe"?

Tags: meaning, word-order, dialogue, emphasis, quotative-inversion

Does the subject/verb order make a difference when writing a dialog tag?

> "The sky is blue," **Joe said**.
>
> "The sky is blue," **said Joe**.

Is one preferable over the other? Does one emphasize the speaker (or the method of speech, such as **shout**) more than the other?

(Personally, I would use the second form to emphasize that *Joe* made the statement)

Comment: Now I am earwormed with "I dreamed I saw Joe Hill last night" - which is actually a pretty good example of the emotional differences among the 4 ways to write that simple sentence - Joe said x; said Joe, x; x, said Joe; and x, Joe said. http://struggle.ws/songs/usa/joehilldream.html

Comment: @Kate Gregory: I think Alfred Hayes's poem (set to music by Earl Robinson later) is really just stylistic variations. I can't see emotional or other semantic nuances embodied in any particular inversion. But I do see significance in the fact that all permutations are present, and in most renditions the singer uses both present and past tense *(said/says)*, giving a sense of universality and timelessness to the subject matter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think "said Joe, I didn't die" is way more powerful than "I didn't die, said Joe". But poetry is personal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP's second version is standard usage, which is why @Barrie calls it the "uninverted form". But note he's only referring to inversion of *subject - verb* (the *object* here being the quoted speech).

The most common structure for English sentences is *subject - verb - object*...

> Joe said "The sky is blue".

...and the most common "sentence inversion" is *object - verb subject*...

> "The sky is blue," said Joe.

There's nothing "ungrammatical" about *object - subject - verb* as in OP's first version, which may be prefered for stylistic reasons in some contexts. And least common, *verb - subject - object* is still perfectly valid English too...

> Said Joe, "The sky is blue".

...but you'd normally only see this in poetic or other stylised writing, rather than in speech.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I can see this inversion being used in normal speech or writing, as a means to emphasize the fact that it was Joe, and not someone else, who said something.

Comment: Nah - the *standard* version is the first one above, and if you needed to emphasise that it was Joe rather than someone else, that's what you'd use anyway - possibly with vocal stress (or italics in writing) to be *really* emphatic. The last version above is *only* poetic, and like the others, it implies no special emphasis in itself. Unlike the others, the last one is the only one where you couldn't lay stress on the word *"said"* to emphasise that Joe *spoke*, rather than *screamed*, or *wrote*, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Both may be used after what is said, but only the uninverted form is normally used before what is said.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Browne and King have to say in [Self-Editing for Fiction Writers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003JBI2YI):

> Place the character’s name or pronoun first in a speaker attribution (“Dave said”). Reversing
>   the two (“said Dave”), though often done, is less professional. It has a slightly 
>   old-fashioned, first-grade-reader flavor (“Run spot, run” said Jane). After all, “said he” 
>   fell out of favor sometime during the Taft administration.

King, Dave; Browne, Renni (2010-06-03). Self-Editing for Fiction Writers, Second Edition: How to Edit Yourself Into Print (Kindle Locations 1120-1122). Harper Collins, Inc.. Kindle Edition.

Comment: Yes, I agree that style preferences are changing.